# Failed to set checkbox "checked" and "unchecked" on the basis of "Session Result " in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, session, checkbox

In document.ready i want to get "Sessions value" either **true** or **false** and on the basis of session value i want to set checkbox status either **checked** or **unchecked** but i am failed to do so......
**CODE:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    //checkBoxStatusUser1("false");
    //setCheckBoxStatus();  
    var php_var = <?php echo json_encode(Yii::app()->session['var']);?>;

             alert("if:" + php_var);
            document.getElementById("activeStatus").checked = php_var;
            checkBoxStatusUser1(php_var);

        });
```

when writing this

```
document.getElementById("activeStatus").checked = php_var;
```

its always setting checkbox checked even alert shows `php_var` value **false** and when putting  `document.getElementById(activeStatus).checked = php_var;`
        in `document.ready()` getting error

```
**"TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null 
   document.getElementById(activeStatus).checked = php_var;"**
```

Comment: And what does the _output_ of your PHP code actually look like in the source code that is created …? `var php_var =` … what is on the right side of that equal sign?

Comment: var php_var = false ; when it is false then it must unchecked my checkbox and when php_var = true then it must checked my checkbox